# Running R script in secureCRT

Tags: r

I tried to run a R script in secureCRT with the command line:

```
Rscript file.R.
```

But it returned as:

> -bash: Rscript: command not found

Could anyone tell me what I should do? I am newbie for this. Thank you!

Comment: Rscript is not installed or is not in your PATH

Comment: Thank you! But I do installed the Rscript, I found it in E:\statistics\R\R-3.1.2\bin\Rscript. And I don't know where to add the path.

Comment: How are you getting a `bash` error on Windows?  If you're using SecureCRT I would think you're probably ssh'ing into another (linux?) system. I know it's possible to have a `bash` shell under windows (e.g. using `cygwin`) but until you clarify your environment, help will be impossible.